# How to make a self signed certificate openssl generated 4096 bit encrypted ssl certificate as trusted in ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-9.10

I have an Apache server (2.4.3) with php5 and MySQL.

I generated a self-signed certificate, which I get a warning about, as the certificate is not trusted.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Clarification needed - do you want to make *your* browser(s) trust the certificate, or make it a trusted certificate for the visitors to your website?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a self-signed certificate, would you be open to getting a free SSL certificate from [startssl.com](http://www.startssl.com)?  That's what I've been doing for my personal web sites.

If that's not an option, you'll want to import either your self-signed certificate or the CA that you used to sign that certificate into your browser and set it to be trusted.  The method for doing this is browser-specific.

The page at http://tech.kaazing.com/documentation/jms/3.3/security/p_tls_clientapp.html has a section called "To Import Self-Signed Certificates into a Web Browser" that explains how to import certificates into several browsers.